# How to add custom tool tip for Line chart - DOJO

Tags: dojox.charting

I am unable to add custom tooltip for `type:'Lines'` charts, as I did for clusturedbar and pie charts.
This is the code I am using..

```
    makeCharts = function(){

    var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart");
    chart1.addPlot("default",{
                 type: 'Lines',
                 markers: true,
                 tension: 'S',
                 lines: true,
                 areas: false,
                 labelOffset: -30,
                 labels:true,
                 shadows: { dx:10, dy:12, dw:12 }
    });
    chart1.addAxis("x");
    chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical: true});
    chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [{y:1, tooltip:'bla bla'}, 
                                          {y:2, tooltip:'bla bla'}, 
                                          {y:2, tooltip:'bla bla'}, 
                                          {y:3, tooltip:'bla bla'}, 
                                          {y:4, tooltip:'bla bla'}, 
                                          {y:5, tooltip:'bla bla'}, 
                                          {y:5, tooltip:'bla bla'}, 
                                          {y:7, tooltip:'bla bla'}]
            );
    new dojox.charting.action2d.Magnify(chart1, 'default');
        new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart1, 'default');
    chart1.render();
};

dojo.addOnLoad(makeCharts);
```

Note: if I am using the json notation in the add series `({y:1, tooltip:'blabla'})`, even chart is not shown up. Chart is coming only when I give `addseries('series 1', [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6]);`
Can anyone tell me what is the wrong in my code to get custom tooltip?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to do this for a Dojo line chart - had to change to an x,y chart as it seems lines only takes an array of numbers. This example helped me - 
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_event2d.html

An array of x: and y: and tooltip: works

```
{x: 1, y: 2, tooltip: "hello"}, {...}
```

If like me you want x to be a set of dates or other non numerical markers then just add ->

```
chart1.addAxis("x", {
labels: [
    {value: 0, text: "20110901"},
    {value: 1, text: "20110902"},
    {value: 2, text: "20110903"},
    ... etc
],
rotation: 90})
```